# How to make many-to-many relationship in Oracle 11g using nested tables and created user defined types?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, many-to-many, user-defined-types

I'm using Oracle 11g. I'm working on simple student project for library. I have to create ORDB so I created my types as objects. My Book type and Author type are like following:

```
CREATE Type AuthorT AS OBJECT(
        AuthorID NUMBER,
        AuthorName VARCHAR(100),
        PlaceID ref PlaceT
        -- collection of books
);


CREATE TYPE BookT AS OBJECT(
        BookID NUMBER,
        ISBN Varchar(100),
        BookName VARCHAR(200),
        PublishedDate Date,
        GenreID ref GenreT,
        PublisherID ref PublisherT
        -- collection of authors
    );
```

Now I have to create tables from these types. My problem is next: I have to do following:

```
CREATE TYPE Author AS TABLE OF AuthorT;
CREATE TYPE Book AS TABLE OF BookT;
```

But, this looks like circle to me, Author has Books, and Books have Authors, so I cannot create these tables which I suppose to use like nested tables???

I'm not sure if question is clear, but I hope somebody could help me. I would not do this this way, but I have to since this is my homework.
Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to a purely object-oriented design. IMO in an object-relational design you'd have a table which holds BookT objects, another that holds AuthorT objects, and another that represents the relationships between books and authors. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Yes, I know I could do that with one JOINT table, but then I loose nested table in my normal Book table that holds BookT, and Author table that holds Author, that's the main problem for me @BobJarvis.

Answer (score 0):

In an object-relational design, which is what you want to do with Oracle ORDB, you must store which Book is related to which Author.

This means you must have a table that associate `BookId` to `AuthorId`:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK_AUTHOR (
  BookId NUMBER,
  AuthorId NUMBER
);
```

This allows accounting for books that have multiple authors.